# yii 2 : override user model

Tags: model, yii2

How to override user model properly in yii2?

For example, I want to override common\models\User.php

I created frontend\models\User.php with the following code :

```
  namespace frontend\models;


  use common\models\User as BaseUser;

  class User extends BaseUser
  {

   public static function tableName()
  {
    return '{{%accounts}}';
  }
  ...
```

In main.php, when I add

```
     'user'=>array(
        'class' => 'frontend\models\User',
    ),
```

I get error 
Setting unknown property: frontend\models\User::identityClass

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 things you can set up:
1)

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
],
```

and 2

```
'user' => [
    'class' => 'frontend\components\User',
],
```

You are switching them around. 'identityClass' is your model, 'class' is the the User component for Yii. By setting identityClass you are telling Yii that the User Component should use frontend\models\User it's identityClass property.

This is the User component https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-framework/blob/master/web/User.php

The previous versions of Yii2 had actually the file frontend\components\User.php already put in (that was extending yii\web\User). I can see why it is more confusing now.

What is the new error you are getting?

Comment: my models extends common/models/User.php as shown in code above

Comment: Sorry I did not see that. BaseUser is actually a Yii class too, anyway it does not matter, see the edited answer answer.

Comment: New error was db related- relation "User" doesn't exists (because default user model where used and my new model has different table name). When I cleared cookies in my browser error dissapeared. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
'user' => [
   'identityClass' => 'frontend\components\User',
   ],
```

in config + delete browser cookies ( seems to be yii2 bug- with cookies present, function renewAuthStatus() loaded common/models/User as identityClass and produced another error)

Comment: It should be 'user' => [
   'identityClass' => 'frontend\models\User',
   ], see my answer for the difference between setting the identityClass and the class.