# yii2 override user component gives the following errror: The identity object must implement IdentityInterface

Tags: php, yii2, overriding, yii2-advanced-app, extend

common\config\main.php:

```
'components' => [
     'user' => [
               'class' => 'common\components\extended\User',
               'identityClass' => 'common\models\Users',
     ],
],
```

reference for the above code comes from: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authentication ,
https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/issues/6 ,
and
[yii 2 : override user model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230383/yii-2-override-user-model)

The error:

```
yii\base\InvalidValueException
The identity object must implement IdentityInterface.
```

Setup:

yii2-advanced-app

php 7.0

component: common\components\extended\User looks like this:

```
namespace common\components\extended;
...
class User extends Component
{
```

it is the same file as 'vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php' with a new namespace and some minor modifications (the 'can' function and a few others)

identityClass: common\models\Users looks like this:

```
namespace common\models;
...
class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
```

removing the line "'identityClass' => 'common\models\Users'," from the config file has no effect on the error message

removing the line "'class' => 'common\components\extended\User'," lets the code run right into ' vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php' where it errors because of non standard rbac setup which required that function 'public function can($permissionName, $params = [], $allowCaching = true)...' be overwritten.

Desire: Override 'vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php' with 'common\components\extended\User'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ps. Have tried: turning it off and on again, cleared cache...

Comment: It seems everything should be ok with your code. Does Users really implement this Interface?

Comment: Did you implement methods from that interface??

Comment: You should not copy the whole class, try extend base class and override only this one method you need to change. Most likely you copied something wrong and/or did not updated namespaces correctly.

Comment: After namespace you have row like "use yii\web\IdentityInterface;"?

Comment: I had the same problem few times ago and I remember just I was make mistake in  configuration between common, frontend and backend. What I would like to suggest to you, is to install dektrium user extension